# Duumvir vs Duovir

Tags: vocabulary

A Duumvir, or Duovir, is one member of a two-man council.

Why are there two spellings, what does the nuance imply, and which one is correct under which circumstance?

Comment: Interesting question. Lewis & Short suggest *duumvir* is "less correct": *dŭŏvir , vĭri, and usu. plur. dŭŏvĭri (less correctly dŭumvĭri , Zumpt, Gram. § 124; Krebs, Antibarb. p. 391; in MSS. and Inscr. usu. II. vir, II. viri;*